# Elasticsearch fuzzy search confusion

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have this query

```
   :body=>
    {:query=>
      {:bool=>
        {:filter=>
          {:bool=>
            {:must=>
              [{:range=>
                 {:model_updated_by_patient_at=>
                   {:gte=>Thu, 03 Jan 2019 05:00:00 +0000,
                    :lt=>Fri, 11 Jan 2019 05:00:00 +0000}}},
               {:bool=>
                 {:should=>
                   [{:multi_match=>
                      {:fields=>["story_markdown"],
                       :query=>"suprspecial",
                       :max_expansions=>50,
                       :fuzziness=>"AUTO"}}]}}]}}}}
```

where the key thing being searched being 'suprspecial'

I have two posts in the time range one with text 'superspecial' and one with text 'sprspecial', however only 'superspecial' is returned from that search even though they're both <2 Levenshtein edits away https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness.

What am I not getting here?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this is not because of the range query part?

Comment: @PiotrPradzynski turned out there's an english analyzer on that field that's stubbing english words and returning some unexpected matches